# A question on Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, superposition

Faraday's law  states that $$\varepsilon=-\frac{d{\phi}}{dt}$$ where $\phi$ is the magnetic flux and $\varepsilon$ is the induced emf.

If the object is symmetric, it's easy to determine across which points the emf is induced. However, if I had a charged unsymmetric object like a scalene triangle, across which points is the emf induced?

The below diagram is just for reference

[image]

I think that, if the principle of superposition works here, the emf is induced across each rod, and then we calculuate the effective emf, using the laws for batteries in series and parallel. Am I right? If so, how would this work if the circuit had no resistance and the emf across the top branch (in my picture) is not equal to the  emf in the bottom branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you are right. The emf induced does follow the principle of superposition.
For the second question, the emf in a circuit without resistance cannot simply be analysed using electrostatics. As you can see, if there is any emf appeared, the current across the circuit would go up to infinite. But the situation is not that simple if your emf is produced by a change of magnetic flux. As long as the current increases, it almost suddenly (I say almost because the change transmits at the speed of light) produces a magnetic field which is against the changing of original magnetic field, which is called Lenz' Law. There wouldn't be such a problem that the emf across the top branch is not equal to the emf in the bottom branch. The secondary magnetic field produced by induced field can perfectly fix the change of your original field at every moment. But emf in the loop remains zero.

Answer (score 2):

The induced current in your triangular conductor would be the same as in a circle of the same area if $\Phi$ changes in this area. Thats what the law says, since $\Phi=B\cdot A$, so $\frac{d \phi}{dt}=A\cdot\frac{dB}{dt}$

Comment: Thanks for th reply! I'm not sure I fully get you, why would the urrent be the same as in that of a circle of equal area. I allso didn't get how the effective emf for the same would be calculated